# EOFError when using Python "cPickle.load" to load a C++-written binary file

Tags: python, c++, pickle, binaryfiles

I wrote a binary file using C++ `fwrite` and try to using `cPickle.load` to load this file. However I got errors

```
 data = pickle.load(f)
 EOFError
```

My C++ write file code is

```
FILE* bp = fopen("res.bin", "wb");
for(int i = 0; i < 512 ; i++){
    float tmp = i;
    fwrite(&tmp, sizeof(float), 1, bp);
}
fclose (bp);
```

My Python load code is

```
 import cPickle as pickle
 f =  open("res.bin", "rb")
 data = pickle.load(f)
 f.close()
```

Please help with this issue. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by numpy...
It seem like `pickle.load` cannot be used to load c++ binary file. So I use numpy.fromfile

```
data =  np.fromfile("res.bin", dtype='float32')
```